Spring Data Jpa Query Methods Enum casting error
I am using spring data jpa, hibernate and postgresql. I have enum field in entity field. There is no error on save operation, because i added ColumnTransformer write attribute. But, when read operations, it throws error

ERROR: operator does not exist: enum_alpha = character varying. No
operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
add explicit type casts.

enum
public enum EnumAlpha {

    A("a"),
    B("b");

    public String text;

}

entity
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    ...

    private Long someId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ColumnTransformer(write = "?::myschema.enum_alpha")
    private EnumAlpha alpha;

    ....

}

repository
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    boolean existsBySomeIdAndAlpha(Long someId, EnumAlpha alpha);

}

postgresql enum type
          CREATE TYPE enum_alpha AS ENUM (
                'A',
                'B');

I tried ColumnTransformer read attribute as well, but not working. I dont want to use native query or query annotation at repository level. I want to use query methods. Is there any solution? Thanks

Adding read attribute as varchar solved my problem.
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ColumnTransformer(read = "alpha::varchar", write = "?::myschema.enum_alpha")
private EnumAlpha alpha;

